# Neighbours of a cell in the borders of a matrix

Tags: matrix, neighbours

I'm facing some issues to find the neighbours in a matrix. I'm trying not to put a lot of `if` statements in the code because I'm pretty sure there's a better way to do it but I don't know exactly how.

To simplify, let's say we have the following matrix:

```
 1  2  3  4  5  
 6  7  8  9  6  
 1  2  3  4  5  
 2  3  4  6  7
```

Considering the cell `[2,2] = 3`, the neighbours would be `(i,j-1)`,`(i-1,j)`,`(i+1,j)`,`(i,j+1)`,`(i+1,j+1)`,`(i-1,j-1)`. I created a "mask" for it using a `for-loop` like this, where `inicio[0]` is the i-coordinate of my current element (2 in the example) and `inicio[1]` is the j-coordinate (also 2 for element 3). Also, I'm considering the element must be in the center of the mask.

```
 for(k=inicio[0]-1;k<inicio[0]+1;k++){
     for(z=inicio[1]-1;z<inicio[1]+1;z++)
         if(k!=0 || z!=0) //jump the current cell
```

However, I don't know how to treat the elements in the borders. If I want to find the neighbours of element `[0,0] = 1` for example, considering the element must be in the middle of the mask like this:

```
x x x  
x 1 2    
x 6 7
```

How can I treat those `X` elements? I thought of initializing the borders on zero but I'm thinking this is not the proper way to do it. So if anyone can explain a better way to do it or an algorithm, I will be glad.

Comment: *How can I treat those X elements? I thought of initialing the borders on zero* That's a perfectly sensible and widely-used approach to resolve the problem you outline.  That border is sometimes known as a *halo* in the literature, or sometimes as *ghost cells*.  The value you put in the ghost cells is problem-specific.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I actually thought this works for a small problem and I used once but if we have a large matrix it wouldn't be a problem to use it? A lot of elements will be added in this case so I keep thinking maybe it's not correct in a generic case but i don't know.

Comment: *if we have a large matrix it wouldn't be a problem to use it*  Well, the number of halo element grows as `4n` while the number of matrix elements grows as `n^2`.  Whether that's a problem or not is very problem and system specific.  But, I repeat, it's an approach taken by many codes operating on arrays.